# git merge overwrites instead of merges regardless of what I do

Tags: git

Colleague and I wanted to merge a codebase that we had been working on separately for some time. It just overwrote my files with his.

Here's what we did:

Colleague cloned my repository.

```
git clone etc.
```

Then made a branch

```
git branch -b sparkles
```

Then they overwrote some files with their own that they had been working on.
Then commit & push

```
git add .
git commit -m "added my files"
git push -u origin sparkles
```

On my end, I wanted to merge their CHANGES... So I make a temporary branch because I know this probably won't go well...

```
git checkout -b merge-try-1
```

Then I grab their branch off remote...

```
git fetch
git checkout -b sparkles origin/sparkles
git pull
```

And make a temporary "copy"

```
git branch -b merge-sparkles
```

Then move onto my branch for trying to merge to...

```
git checkout merge-try-1
```

Then do a merge...

```
git merge merge-sparkles
```

And it just overwrites the files with files from merge-sparkles, as if I had used `theirs`. Obviously I wanted to merge their changes not overwrite my files.

So made a new branch merge-try-2 and tried merge like so:

```
git merge -s recursive -X patient merge-sparkles
```

And everything just gets overwritten and not merged, again.

I feel like I must be fundamentally misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have a common ancestor before your developments. I see two possibilities to merge your work with your collegue:

### merging strategy

keep your same strategy; but when your collegue clones your repository; go back in history to a moment before your developments. Create the branch **sparkles** there; and continue with all other steps like before.

```
git branch sparkles <common-ancestor-commit>
```

### selective adding

When your collegue cloned your repository; don't just run `git add .`; but use `git add -p`. This way you can selectively add the work of your collegue; checking at each step not to break your developments. This way you will end up with common code that contains both your developments. Note that you will manually have to make sure the code now contains both developments.